# knockout if bindings not evaluated till after initial render

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've noticed on firefox 3.6 that even though an if binding evaluates to false the DOM tree will always be rendered first then the binding gets evaluated and the DOM tree will get removed. This results in the screen flickering:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m0bxy9p0/)

```
<!-- ko ifnot: IsEditing -->
    <span data-bind="{ text:SystemName }"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: IsEditing -->
    <input type="text" id="SystemName" data-bind="{ value: SystemName }" />
    <h1>YOU SHOULD NOT SEE ME ON FIRST RENDER</h1>
<!-- /ko -->
```

When using Firefox 3.6 you will notice that the text "YOU SHOULD NOT SEE ME ON FIRST RENDER" flashes up then disappears.

How can I resolve this issue? Will using a template binding help?

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

Comment: surely using template binding will solve the issue as you can see you are using empty container which will run only once. Once the page is rendered you will not have any control over to render the part again. Instead if using template you can re-render the part.

Comment: I doubt using a template binding will help. A general fix that might work for you, is to add a lifetime cycle to your viewmodels: to start, give them an 'activate'-method. Only when this method is complete, actually show the view to the user. This way, any 'flickering' on the page based on the initial load activity will be hidden from the user, they will always see the final page immediatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can go through

```
<button data-bind="click: click">Toogle IsEditing</button>

<div data-bind='template:{ name: "temp", data: IsEditing }'></div>

<script id='temp' type='text/html'>
    <!-- ko ifnot: $root.IsEditing -->
        <span data-bind="{ text:$root.SystemName }"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: $root.IsEditing -->
        <input type="text" id="SystemName" data-bind="{ value: $root.SystemName }" />
        <h1>YOU SHOULD NOT SEE ME ON FIRST RENDER</h1>
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

And

```
var ViewModel = function()
{
    var self = this;
    self.SystemName = ko.observable('Test SystemName');
    self.IsEditing = ko.observable(false);
    self.click = function()
    {
        self.IsEditing(!self.IsEditing());
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

### Fiddle Demo